# Wordpress Detected usage of a non-validated input variable:

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

```
$events_meta['ets_images'] = ($_POST['ets_images'] ) ?  $_POST['ets_images'] : '';
```

I'm getting this error

> Detected usage of a non-validated input variable: $_POST

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to know what the error means. It's telling you, that you are using the data in `$_POST['ets_images']` without checking and sanitizing its contents first. This could be harmful and dangerous in your application, since nothing is stopping an attacker to misuse `$_POST['ets_images']`.

```
<?php

$events_meta['ets_images'] = '';

if (isset($_POST['ets_images'])) {
    $events_meta['ets_images'] = strval($_POST['ets_images']); // make sure it will be a string
}

?>
```

Comment: and how to validate it ?

Comment: I've added some example code. You need to check the contents of the `$_POST` variable before using it.